# Jade causes waterfall of requests and crashes website

Tags: pug, mean-stack

### TL;DR with examples:

This jade snippet causes website to send endless stream of GET requests to server like shown below:

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
  .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
    .container
      .navbar-header
        a.navbar-brand(href="/") MEANapp
          h6 test
      .navbar-collapse.collapse
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
          li
            a(href="/") Home
        div(ng-include="'partials/account/navbar-login'")

  section.content
    div(ng-view)

    footer.container.text-center
      p &copy; MEAN app copyright
```

request log:

```
    GET /vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js?_=1455122194802 200 1ms - 57.16kb
    GET /vendor/toastr/toastr.js?_=1455122194803 200 1ms - 12.01kb
    GET /vendor/angular/angular.js?_=1455122194804 200 3ms - 771.86kb
    .
    .
    .
    GET /app/admin/mvUserListCtrl.js?_=1455122194815 200 1ms - 117b
    GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js?_=1455122194816 200 1ms - 236.47kb
    GET /vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js?_=1455122194817 200 1ms - 57.16kb
    GET /vendor/toastr/toastr.js?_=1455122194818 200 0ms - 12.01kb
```

And this one causes expected behaviour, which is redirection to main page '/':

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
  .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
    .container
      .navbar-header
        a.navbar-brand(href="/") Multivision
          h6 -Extreme Tech Training
      .navbar-collapse.collapse
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
          li
            a(href="/") Home
        div(ng-include="'/partials/account/navbar-login'")

  section.content
    div(ng-view)

    footer.container.text-center
        p &copy; 2013 Multivision Corp International Ltd.
```

My question is really simple. Why template language with little to zero logic can cause such a mess?

### Context

I was developing website in MEAN stack following the course, and I stumbled upon weirdest bug I've seen.

To give you basic idea I've protected some resource on path '/admin/users' so only authorized user can access it.

Then, when I tried to access it with Unauthorized user Chrome shown bunch of errors, mostly related to $routeProvider and $rootScope:

```
[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I couldn't find cause myself so I've found someones git repo with completed project and and carefully investigated every line of project. When no code with actual logic was left I switched to jade template from repo. Voila.
What can cause that behaviour?
Maybe angular or node (only two pieces of project with routing logic) have conflict with jade engine?

Comment: "My question is really simple. Why template language with little to zero logic can cause such a mess?" Simple, that's not where your problem is, it's just where the visual signs of the deeper problem are I'd say your layout template may be broken (probably not) or more likely, the server logic is broken. Start by reviewing the express code that handles serving those pages and work backwards from there.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks for reply! That's the problem, I've reviewed every line of server-side code, and even copied every bit that didn't matter from repo that works. After it turned out not to make any difference, I changed my code back to what I've had earlier ans tried multiple times with one template and the other. Everytime, first one causes bug, and other doesn't. 
I'd love if you could maybe look at it on you machine? I can provide repo, so you can see it with your own eyes :)

Comment: A repo would be very helpful. It looks like reviewing the routes might indeed be needed. I'm not overly familiar with Node (working on learning it slowly). However, wonder if it those routes should be including a query (like `?_=1455122194818` on the last one).

Comment: @Nuclearman we can look at it together, as it's interesting bug. Maybe you won't have to deal with it someday after we figure it out ;) here's the repo [link](https://github.com/ketus/Mean-app)
I can send you instructions on how to reproduce the bug on github.